# pythonanywhere 404 error

Tags: python, http-status-code-404, flask, pythonanywhere

I'm building an app in pythonanywhere using the [Flask Mega Tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) and it works fine when I run in on my pc.  When I upload it to PA it gets a 404 error.

my structure

```
/microblog
    /flask (virtualenv setup)
    /app
        __init__.py
        views.py
```

my wsgi file

```
import sys
project_home = u'/home/thefritobandit/microblog/app'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path
from __init__ import app as application
```

my **init**.py file

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import views
```

my views.py file

```
from app import app
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello World!"
```

I'm sure it's something stupid but any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

--edit-- forgot to copy over the import at the bottom of my init file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change 
 `project_home = u'/home/thefritobandit/microblog/app` 
to 
`project_home = u'/home/thefritobandit/microblog`

and in your wsgi file change 
 `from __init__ import app as application`
 to
 `from app import app as application`.

Comment: sorry, just forgot to copy that over from my file...edited my post to include the last line. thanks

Comment: @thefritobandit: see the updated post. And why do you want to set up flask in virtualenv on PAW? Its already installed there.

Comment: i'm pretty new at this so i'm just following the tutorial.  would you recommend that i just drop that portion?

Comment: @thefritobandit yes delete that part! and reload the web app after applying above mentioned change.

Comment: that was it! thank you! i would upvote you but i don't have the required 15 reputation.  sorry