# The Requested url not found. 404 error in pythonanywhere

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

I have Flask app, and I wanted to run in pythonanywhere.com. I have followed the links [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53867776/deploying-python-flask-app-on-web-using-pythonanywhere), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584241/pythonanywhere-404-error), couldn't resolve the issue. My flask app name is `tourismmining` and the contents of the directory is listed under

### Application Structure

My application is structured in the below way.

```
tourismmining
|-> instance
|-> mining
|-> resources
|-> entry.py
|-> installation.txt
|-> License
|-> Procfile
|-> README.rst
|-> requirements.txt
```

The core application is in the directory `mining` and is structured in the following way

```
mining
|-> config
|-> db
|-> exceptions
|-> files
|-> forms
|-> logs
|-> models
|-> sink
|-> static
|-> templates
|-> __init__.py
|-> main.py
|-> utils.py
```

So, just by flask local server, I used to run the below command

```
 cd tourismmining

 python -m mining.main
```

and below is the output

[image]

In touristmining, I have written an another file named entry.py, and it contains

```py
      from mining import app

      if __name__ == '__main__':
          app.run(debug=True)
```

And I run the file `entry.py` using the below command

```
   cd tourismmining

   python entry.py
```

[image]

Now, after uploading the same code in to pythonanywhere, the directory structure is given below

[image]

Setting up the virtual environment and tried two ways of configuring the wsgi file which are given below

```py
import sys
path = '/home/s1782662edin/tourismmining'
if path not in sys.path:
   sys.path.insert(0, path)

from mining import app as application
```

```py
import sys
path = '/home/s1782662edin/tourismmining'
if path not in sys.path:
   sys.path.insert(0, path)

from entry import app as application
```

And reload the website, nothing worked out. Its says

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your 
spelling and try again.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have routes defined and that the code for defining the routes is run when app is imported from mining.